# Python True Copy Within a Class

Tags: python, list, class, deep-copy

For some reason, I have a list that keeps getting modified despite being explicitly a deep copy. It appears to be unmodified as it goes through the loop, but it suddenly is modified once it exists? I must be missing something that pertains to Python's rules and logic, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
def all_possible_states(self):
    #creates many variations of a board from the available set of moves
    to_return = [] #list of possible board states to return
    #print(self.availible_moves)
    list_to_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.availible_moves)
    for item in self.availible_moves:
        print('loop')
        
        #append possible board state to list. set of availible moves for that board is one less. Done by removing item from that move list
        to_return.append(board(self.player, copy.deepcopy(self.board.copy()), list_to_copy, self.plays, self.score, copy.deepcopy(item)))
        
        #print(item)
        print( self.avalible_moves) #shows the total set of moves. This is unmodified whenever it prints
        print(list_to_copy)#deep copy of the original list. This is unmodified when it prints
        print(to_return[len(to_return) - 1].availible_moves) #List of moves left availible for the board, this slowly shrinks for some reason each loop
    
    
    print(self.availible_moves) #this is the original list, but it's not basically been cut all the way down for some reason
    return to_return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the local variable `list_to_copy` is the deepcopy, not `self.availible_moves`. You are saving a deepcopy of `self.availible_moves` and it is being stored in the `list_to_copy` variable you defined. `list_to_copy` never changes as expected from a deepcopy. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you want, at the end you can reset `self.availible_moves` to be equal to `list_to_copy` and then it will be as if it never changed.

**EDIT:**

Actually, I think you have a spelling mistake, notice that you `print(self.avalible_moves)` and you are saying its not changing, when really what is changing is `self.availible_moves`. Notice the extra letter i in the first expression. This definitely is one of your problems.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through a list of moves to generate a list of board states to stick into a different list. When I call the constructor, it reduces the number of available moves by one for that copy. The original copy should be unmodified. Problem is, the original move list is getting cut down each time the constructor is called. This has the side effect of causing the iteration to skip items in self.availible_moves. What I don't understand is when I print it in loop, it's fine. When I exit the loop, it suddenly is cut down like the true copy went through the constructor.

Comment: @RandomAsian Check out my edit

Comment: It would appear a typo was the issue. I ended up accidently misspelling in my constructor which ended up not getting flagged somehow.